# Inserting records from within cursor versus inserting them at the very end using temp tables in the cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I know cursors are not efficient to use but based on business I will be just processing 20 records at the max so they will be OK.

I have following 2 approaches in mind to implement this:

Approach 1:

1. Cursor open
2. Do some heavy calculations
3. Insert record in a table 1(actual table in database)
4. Cursor Close

Approach 2:

1. Declare temporary table 1(exactly same table 1)
2. Cursor Open
3. Do heavy calculations
4. Insert record in temporary table 1
5. Cursor Close
6. Insert records into table 1 from temporary table 1

Comment: Use "Approach 2" it's both more efficient and avoids the need to lock the target table for the duration of the cursor loop.

Comment: You can't use "Approach 1" in all situations; like when any one of your calculation methods uses "table 1" ;).

Comment: Procedural code like cursors is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Thank you everybody, I will follow approach 2.